Javascript how to return native string symbol iterator when string not include "!"?
I have meet some problem , i want to return native string symbol iterator when string not include "!"
Have fixed see the updated code,thanks
var org=String.prototype[Symbol.iterator]
Object.defineProperty(
    String.prototype,Symbol.iterator,
                {
    writable: true, configurable: true, enumerable: false,
    value:function iterator(){
      // fixed 
      if(!(this).includes("!")){
        return org.call(this);
      }
    var i, inc, done = false,str=this

    return {

    next() {

    
      do custom iterator
    
     } };
    } }
    ); 

Any pepole can help , thanks!

Please note that it is considered "bad practice" to modify javascript built-ins like you are doing here

Hi Jaromanda X, have changed the code , but i don't know how to return the native string iterator,thanks reply

save String.prototype[Symbol.iterator] in a variable before you overwrite it ... return that variable as required

Hi Jaromanda X, i have changed the code, but have below error
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: this.includes is not a function

that's nothing like what I suggested. clearly that code is invalid syntax

Hi Jaromanda X , have fixed the problem, thanks for your help!

please close or answer your question otherwise it deceives answerers, since you solved your problem
